# Function prototype for unused function

Tags: c, compilation

I am working on a piece of code which will be used for multiple projects, and I just realized I can have function prototype only (without the actual implementation) if the call of the function is protected with an if.
Sample:

```
#ifndef __TEST_H
#define __TEST_H

uint32_t test_init(void);

#if CONFIG_TEST

bool is_test_supported(void);

#else
static inline bool is_test_supported(void)
{
    return false;
}
#endif
#endif
```

and in the c file I have

```
...
if (is_test_supported())
    test_init();
...
```

on a system that CONFIG_TEST is not defined, the above code still compiles fine. I would imagine this is because the compiler is smart enough to understand the code path is never executed, is this correct and is this behavior portable? The compiler is clang.

EDIT: corrected some mistake on the function names...

Comment: What function are you talking about specifically: `test_is_supported` or `test_init`? Which one do you leave without the actual implementation?

Comment: @AnT I'm pretty sure his question is about `test_init()`, which is declared but has no implementation.

Comment: sorry guys, it should be if (test_is_supported()). and the function I am talking about is test_init()

Comment: @Barmar: But in the first branch `is_test_supported` is also declared with no implementation. How does that work?

Comment: @AnT His question is about the second branch, where he defines `is_test_supported()` and it always returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* depend on a simple C `if` to remove a function call. It so happens that the compiler optimizes the test

```
if(test_is_supported())
```

to

```
if(false)
```

via inlining, and then further optimizes the subsequent `test_init()` out as dead code.

**However**, these optimizations are *not guaranteed*. If you were compiling with no optimizations, for example, there's every chance that the optimizations won't happen and the function call will be generated. In that case, even if it never executes, the linker will need a definition of the function or it will fail.

The *safer* approach is to use an `#if` to remove the code completely:

```
#if CONFIG_TEST
if(test_is_supported())
    test_init();
#endif
```

This will guarantee that the `if` and subsequent code will not be compiled at all if `CONFIG_TEST` is undefined (i.e. if `test_init()` is not defined).

Comment: For what's worth, I disabled link time optimization and it still compiles fine.  #if is not allowed in c file for this project, so I would think the best bet is to implement test_init() which just returns some invalid value.

Comment: LTO doesn't help - if the call is generated in the one compilation unit, the linker will complain that it can't find the definition (whether or not LTO is enabled - LTO only helps to inline and optimize the call across compilation units).

Answer (score 0):

Formally, function `test_init` is *used* in the code and the definition is required by the language.

However, a smart compiler might figure out the branch protected by `if` is never executed and eliminate the call to `test_init`. If all calls to the function are eliminated by the compiler, then the typical implementation might not be able to diagnose the problem since the function is not *actually* used. "Missing definition" problems for entities with external linkage are typically diagnosed at linking stage. The error is reported when the linker cannot match a function call to a function definition. If there are no calls, there's no need to match anything.

But, again, this is not something you can rely upon. At language level there's no such feature as "static if". Formally C language does not allow you to leave such function undefined, even if they are protected by `if` whose condition is known at compile time.